# How can I tell Firefox to disallow certain sites from opening new windows/tabs?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I want to force certain sites to open every url to the same tab.

I found a plugin, that I cannot recall now, that forces all links to open in the same tab. Only problem is that that plugin set this globally on firefox.
How can I have the same behavior in only the selected sites I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can strip target attribute from links with [TargetKiller](https://addons.mozilla.org/fi/firefox/addon/targetkiller/) extension. It has a "blacklist" option that causes the add-on to only remove link targets on the sites you have specified. The same list can also be configured to do the opposite: target attributes are stripped everywhere except on the listed sites.